# ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Tags: oracle, for-loop, select, plsql, ora-00928

In MYTABLE there are courses and their predecessor courses.
What I am trying to is to find the courses to be taken after the specified course. I am getting missing SELECT keyword error. Why I am getting this error although I have SELECT statement in FOR statement ? Where am I doing wrong ?

```
DECLARE
  coursename varchar2(200) := 'COURSE_101';
  str        varchar2(200);
BEGIN
  WITH DATA AS
    (select (select course_name 
             from MYTABLE 
             WHERE predecessors like ('''%' || coursename||'%''') 
            ) str
     from dual
    )
    FOR cursor1 IN (SELECT str FROM DATA) 
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cursor1);
    END LOOP;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong, WITH factoring clause can't be used that way; you'll have to use it as an inline view, such as this:

```
declare
  coursename varchar2(200) := 'COURSE_101';
  str        varchar2(200);
begin
  for cursor1 in (select str 
                  from (select (select course_name 
                                from mytable 
                                where predecessors like '''%' || coursename||'%'''
                               )  str
                        from dual
                       )
                 ) 
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cursor1.str);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Apart from the fact that it doesn't work (wrong LIKE condition), you OVERcomplicated it. This is how it, actually, *does* something:

```
SQL> create table mytable(course_name  varchar2(20),
  2                       predecessors varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into mytable values ('COURSE_101', 'COURSE_101');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    coursename varchar2(20) := 'COURSE_101';
  3  begin
  4    for cursor1 in (select course_name str
  5                    from mytable
  6                    where predecessors like '%' || coursename || '%'
  7                   )
  8    loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line(cursor1.str);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /
COURSE_101

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Also, is that WHERE clause correct? *PREDECESSORS LIKE COURSENAME*? I'm not saying that it is wrong, just looks somewhat strange.

Comment: Thank you. Your second example worked for me. Actually like condition is not wrong, the reason why it looks complicated is that I want it to be dynamic value as there are lots of data in my table. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To extend @Littlefoot's answer a bit: you can use a common table expression (WITH clause) in your cursor, but the WITH must be part of the cursor SELECT statement, not separate from it:

```
DECLARE
  coursename varchar2(200) := 'COURSE_101';
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (WITH DATA AS (select course_name AS str
                               from MYTABLE 
                               WHERE predecessors like '''%' || coursename||'%''')
               SELECT str FROM DATA)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aRow.str);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Also note that the iteration variable in a cursor FOR-loop represents a row returned by the cursor's SELECT statement, so if you want to display whatever was returned by the cursor you must use dotted-variable notation (e.g. `aRow.str`) to extract fields from the row.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE product
(
PRODUCT_ID int Primary key,
NAME VARCHAR (20) not null,
Batchno int not null,
Rate int not null,
Tax int not null,
Expiredate date not null
);

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUSES(1 , 'vasocare', 32 , 15 , 2 , 01-JAN-2021);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30466358)